# Redirect subdomain to PHP page and mask it

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Basically everybody has their own pages setup at domain.com/site?name=whatever

My host already does subdomains automatically (for example if I were to create a folder named dalton I'd automatically be able to visit dalton.domain.com)

Anyhow I want people to be able to go to whatever.domain.com and for it to actually be querying domain.com/site?name=whatever (I want it to mask it too so they are still on the subdomain)

Any ideas? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set up an `index.php` page which every subdomain points to, you could

- Retrieve the "subdomain" part of the URL
- Create an iFrame that contains the actual page you want to show

This is typically how a lot of domain-hosting companies do "masking".

---

*`index.php`* (abridged):

```
<?php
    //Get subdomain
    $subdomain = array_shift((explode(".",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])));

    //Rewrite URL
    $url = "http://www.domain.com/site?name=" . $subdomain;

    //Create page
    echo "<!doctype html><html><head><title>Page Title</title></head><body style='margin:0;padding:0;'>";

    //Create full-screen iframe with that page as the URL
    echo '<iframe src="'.$url.'" style="border: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%"></iframe>';

    //Close page
    echo "</body></html>";
```

---

Alternatively, you can handle this almost entirely with `.htacccess`:

*`.htaccess`* (abridged):

```
#Use the Rewrite engine
RewriteEngine on

#Doesn't start with "www."
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.

#Check URL is "something.domain.com"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com

#Capture the subdomain and rewrite
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/site?name=/%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Cool so .htaccess sorta works for example swag.domain.com redirects to domain.com/site?name=swag (but it doesn't mask). I tried using your PHP script but it's not working out.

Comment: @DaltonEdwards Yeah that's correct. Either use one solution or the other - but the `.htaccess` solution is probably a lot more manageable and easy to debug!

Comment: I found out how to mask it! I just don't enter the entire URL only the file name RewriteRule ^(.*)$ site.php?name=%1 [L,NC,QSA]